# C# - Why can we inherit an interface twice?

Tags: c#, interface

Both of these C# code versions compile and seem to do the same thing:

**Version A**

```
class Foo : ICollection<string>
{...}
```

**Version B**

```
class Foo : ICollection<string>, IEnumerable<string>
{...}
```

The `ICollection` interface inherits from `IEnumerable`, so `foo` is considered an `IEnumerable` either way.

What's the difference between the two versions and which one should I use?

Comment: Both the same, just ignores that you inherit the same interface twice

Comment: there is no difference. If you know interface x or inherits from interface y, then don't include interface y, but if you can't be bothered checking or don't know, include it, it quite literally makes 0 difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Version A" and "Version B" are functionally equivalent / identical and would get compiled into the same code.

You might only choose for "Version B" if there is a chance that in the future the 2 applied interfaces will not have an inheritance structure (in this case that `ICollection<T>` will no longer extend `IEnumerable<T>`). That whould not happen with these 2 interface types but it might with your own types that you define.